# Can we use Logcat -s option along with -f option

Tags: android, android-logcat

Can we use the -s option of the logcat(which is used to filter the logs of specific tag) along with -f option(which is used to write logs to file)

The problem which I am facing:

In a program, I am writing the logs to a file using following code and it is working fine:

```
String cmd = "logcat -f " + filename.getAbsolutePath();
process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
```

However, When I use the following cmd nothing is written to the file :

```
String cmd = "logcat -s TESTLOGS -f " + filename.getAbsolutePath();
```

Please Help....

Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: According to http://developer.android.com/tools/help/logcat.html, there's no argument to `-s`

Comment: @RC. Thanks for the reply....... Is there any other way to achieve the required functionality.